# Treating a 1 dimensional array as a 2 d

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I am working on an assignment for my school and I have an array with buttons that goes all the way from 0 to 42 and the form is something like this: ( I show it to you with letters so the format is easier to understand, keep in mind  a = 0):

> a b c d e f g
>
> h i j k l m n
>
> o p q r s t u

I want to perform operations like getting the values of x,y coordinates, setting the values of x,y. I've already tried some things but none of them seem to work the way I want them to. And I don't know if it is worth transitioning my assignment to 2D at this point.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] Buttons = new Button[42];
    bool one1 = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            this.Buttons[i] = new Button();
            int x = 50 + (i % 7) * 50;
            int y = 50 + (i / 7) * 50;

            this.Buttons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            this.Buttons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
            this.Buttons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.Buttons[i].TabIndex = i;
            this.Buttons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
            this.Buttons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Buttons[i].Visible = true;

            Buttons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1, index);
            this.Controls.Add(Buttons[i]);
        }
    }
```

Edit: I added the code that generates the array. I tried using something like this:

```
  var startValue = (Button)sender;
int xCenter = startValue.Location.X
int yCenter = startValue.Location.Y
```

But for some reason it didn't work as I wanted. Basically I want to generate code that when the user clicks a button, the code can check the surrounding buttons for information.

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show the code and explain what issues you have with it

Comment: The modulo operator, `%`, is your friend.

Comment: What does *"didn't work as I wanted"* mean? You need to explain what the actual problem is

Answer (score 1):

If you define how many entries you have per row, you can calculate the offset inside the onedimensional array

```
public static void Main() {

    const int elementsPerRow = 5;
    var data = new [] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                       "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
                       "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
                       "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"
                      };

    var aIndex = GetIndex(0, 0, elementsPerRow);
    var eIndex = GetIndex(0, 4, elementsPerRow);
    var pIndex = GetIndex(3, 0, elementsPerRow);
    var tIndex = GetIndex(3, 4, elementsPerRow);

    Console.WriteLine(data[aIndex]); // A
    Console.WriteLine(data[eIndex]); // E
    Console.WriteLine(data[pIndex]); // P
    Console.WriteLine(data[tIndex]); // T
}

public static int GetIndex(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, int elementsPerRow) {
    var index = rowIndex * elementsPerRow + columnIndex;
    return index;
}
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMTr4Z)